Why are ping timestamps garbage in QEMU?
This sort of behavior is consistently reproducible. I'm using Linux guests on a macOS host with QEMU (via UTM, a GUI QEMU frontend).
brennan@eugene ~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.64.110): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 142.250.64.110: icmp_seq=0 ttl=255 time=4106536135042530803712,000 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.64.110: icmp_seq=0 ttl=255 time=4106536135042530803712,000 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 142.250.64.110: icmp_seq=0 ttl=255 time=-7944632498817993801728,000 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 142.250.64.110: icmp_seq=0 ttl=255 time=-7944632498817993801728,000 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 142.250.64.110: icmp_seq=0 ttl=255 time=-7944631970489462423552,000 ms (DUP!)
^C--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, +4 duplicates, 80% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = -7944632498817993801728,000/-3124164939608077893632,000/4106536135042530803712,000/5903842705162658381824,000 ms


Are you assuming the data is bad because the utility is faulty/buddy, or are you asking for help diagnosing network issues? "Garbage" is not a clear enough term for us to deduce what you are actually asking. Please use the EDIT button to present a clearer problem, describe your situation, what you've tried so far to resolve things, etc.
